# jQueryMobile - Call JavaScript from other Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have two files/pages: `fileA.php` and `fileB.php`

`fileB.php` gets called via AJAX from `fileA.php` and passes some data to `fileB.php` via GET.

In `fileA.php`, a FlipSwitch is getting disabled when clicking on it, clicking on it also calls `fileB.php`, where some functions are executed.

What I want now is to re-enable the FlipSwitch in `fileA.php` after the functions in `fileB.php` are done getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, already got it.
I putted the jQuery Call in a variable and run it via deferred.always, then executing the JavaScript Code I needed to re-activate the FlipSwitch, works perfectly now!